# Are spaces allowed after the `@` beginning a declaration in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, declaration

I am looking at Objective-C and I notice, for example, a class-interface declaration begins with `@interface`. Fine, no problema. The text, therefore, suggests no space is permitted between the `@` and `interface`. However, when I pass the following simple example to the GCC compiler in a `*.m` file:

```
@ interface A
@ end
```

the compiler accepts the code without complaint. Can Anyone point Me in the direction of a reference which says explicitly whether or not `@ interface` is also considered acceptable by the Objective-C specification? I found nothing in Apple's 2008 and 2011 documents to say one way or the other besides the simple text alluded to earlier in the question.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: It may be worth noting Emacs performs text coloring based on whether the identifier is a keyword or not; keywords are blue and non-keywords are yellow. The `@interface` colors blue and `@ interface` colors yellow. Similar behavior occurs in Vim.

Comment: C-type languages tend to be loose about where whitespace can appear near symbols. I'm guessing that a space there really doesn't matter, especially if, as you say, it compiles.

Comment: Yeah, I can't recall ever seeing this issue addressed in any of the documentation.  For the most part `@` is used to trigger the Objective-C preprocessor to do special stuff, one way or the other, so it would be the preprocessor, not the C compiler, that decides.  (Good question!)

Comment: Interesting point, Hot Licks, except the Objective-C documentation I have specifies `@interface` is a compiler directive, distinct from preprocessor directives like `#import`.

Comment: So you could do `@                                             interface                       A`?

Comment: `@` processing hasn't been handled by a preprocessor in a long time. Modern ObjC compilers handle it directly as though it were a real language :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no formal specification for Objective-C (beyond [The Objective-C Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html)). There's definitely no BNF-style definition of the whitespace conventions. If it compiles, that's about the closest we have to "legal." This is true of many languages. Perl for instance is best defined as "those strings which the `perl` executable will not reject." (At least in my opinion....)

That said, the correct style is `@interface` without a space. See [Defining a Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html).